# Ways of Passing URL?

Tags: visualforce

Right now I'm constructing a link in a `Visualforce Page` as follows:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Test"><apex:outputLink value="http:someidhere?someparam1=value&param2=value2&id={!tsk.field__c}" target="_blank" >{!tsk.Field__c}</apex:outputlink></apex:column>
```

Is their any other way that I can pass by using http or a method so that I can use that in a page wherever I require it? It would be easy to change the URL value in one place at times required rather than changing in multiples places used in a `Visualforce Page`.

Comment: Use custom setting for this;

Comment: can I pass the value dynamically in custom settings '{!tsk.field__c}'

Comment: I don't think so;

Comment: First of all, you should use the secure transport protocol (`https`). Second of all, that doesn't appear to be a valid url. Are you trying to navigate to the record view?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom label in Salesforce something like that:-

**Custom Label 1:** URIProtocal, value="http://" OR https://" 
**Custom Label 2:** SiteURI, value="someparam1=value&param2=value2&id="

**Implementation**:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Test">
    <apex:outputLink 
          value="{!$Label.URIProtocal}{!$Label.SiteURI}{!tsk.field__c}" target="_blank" >{!tsk.Field__c}
    </apex:outputlink>
</apex:column>
```

**If you love code and robust solution:-**

You can use [`String.format`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm). Example as below:-

**Configuration**
Custom Label = `{0}someparam1=value&param2=value2&id={1};`

Code

```
String templateString = System.Label.xCustomLabel;
String[] values = new String[] {'https://' , tk.field__c};
String formattedString = String.format(templateString, values);
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Test">
    <apex:outputLink>
          value="{!templateString}" target="_blank" >{!tsk.Field__c}
    </apex:outputlink>
</apex:column>
```